# Adding labels to custom icons - Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I'm rendering  a MVT (Mapbox Vector Tiles) layer on my Leaflet map. I'm using custom icons to represent my points, so my vector tile options look like this:

```
var vectorTileOptions = {
maxNativeZoom: 14,
vectorTileLayerStyles: {        
    'vw_meteo_fc': function(properties, zoom) {
        console.log(properties.label);  
        return {
            icon: new L.Icon({
                            iconUrl: 'icons/icon.png',
                            iconSize: [40, 40], // size of the icon
                            iconAnchor: [20, 20], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                        })                            
        }
    }   
},
interactive: true,  // Make sure that this VectorGrid fires mouse/pointer events
getFeatureId: function(f) {
    return f.properties.osm_id;
}
};
```

Is there a way to add labels to these points based on feature subproperty? It can be accessed while rendering the point with: properties.label (console logged in code above).